# How do emails use batch processing sytems?

Tags: operating-systems

Although I understand the definition of batch processing (a method of running software programs called jobs in batches automatically) and some applications of this system (bank statements and payroll and timesheet processing), how do emails use this system? I saw that emails use this system, but how are emails done in batches?

Comment: Please provide some context on where this is coming from.  Why are you asking?  Why do you believe that emails use batch processing systems?  What problem are you trying to solve?